# How to make a simple file dialog on Windows 7?

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, opendialog

I am trying to create a simple file select dialog in VBScript. I have searched around for and answer but not come up with a simple solution. I don't need Filter options or the like.

In extended script I would use  `myFile = File.openDialog()`.

Can someone give me the VBScript equivalent for Windows 7?

Comment: Try `Set oDialog = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")`. Preset `oDialog.Filter` and `oDialog.InitialDir` properties and invoke `intResult = oDialog.ShowOpen`. Then, if `intResult` is non-zero, check `oDialog.FileName` property

Comment: CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog") only works xp? So it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the below snippet using shell script over here https://gist.github.com/mlhaufe/1034241

```
Function BrowseForFile()
Dim shell : Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim file : Set file = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)
BrowseForFile = file.self.Path
End Function 
MsgBox BrowseForFile
```

It seems to work well.  Interested if there's a simple "pure vbs" version.